# How do I change where save and open windows appear on screen in Gnome/Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, gnome

All my popup windows like "Save" or "Open" windows (I am unsure what the proper term would be for these windows) open on my smaller laptop display. I find this annoying and would like them to open on my main external display. Where is the setting that defines on which monitor or where these secondary application windows open in Gnome / Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in https://askubuntu.com/questions/112350/twinview-dialog-boxes-all-open-in-secondary-screen:

1. Install ccsm

```
sudo apt install -y compizconfig-settings-manager
```

2. Go to General -> General Options -> Display Settings
3. From drop down menu of 'Overlapping Output Handling' select 'Prefer smaller output'

Default behavior 'Smart' sometimes is not smart, so you may have to override it by step above. Anyway, some applications have their own rules (i.e. VS Code, which sometimes opens dialog window out of focus).